# Can a file path and file name be extracted in XSL to use in the transform process

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT file that transforms multinode XML files for MS Access and I need to trap the filename of the XML file. I want to use it as additional column in the transform process to add to the tables being populated. Ideally I would like to insert the tag in the "INTERFACE_BATCH" node or the PART_DETAIL node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="INTERFACE_BATCH">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PART_DETAIL">
    <PART_DETAIL>
        <ERP_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="../ERP_NUMBER"/></ERP_NUMBER>
        <PLANT><xsl:value-of select="../PLANT"/></PLANT>
        <PROCESS><xsl:value-of select="../PROCESS"/></PROCESS>
        <STORAGE_LOCATION><xsl:value-of select="../STORAGE_LOCATION"/></STORAGE_LOCATION>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </PART_DETAIL>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT POST: This is the VBA data that I use to upload and transform the XML data

```
 Private Sub btnImportData_Click()
'transform and load xml files into tables
Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    strPath = "\\linbs002\ABI Master Data\ES_XML\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")

' LOAD XSL ONLY ONCE
    xslDoc.Load strPath & "material_new.xsl"
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    While strFile <> ""
' REINITIALIZE DOM OBJECTS
        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

' LOAD XML SOURCE
        xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile

' TRANSFORM SOURCE
        xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
        newDoc.Save strPath & "temp.xml"

' APPEND TO TABLES
        Application.ImportXML strPath & "temp.xml", acAppendData

        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

' RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing

'delete unneeded tables
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "DESCRIPTOR"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTY"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "ImportErrors"

'append data to table ES_Materials
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "EngineeringSpares", acViewNormal

'clear data from temp tables
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE MATERIAL_ITEM.* FROM MATERIAL_ITEM;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE PART_DETAIL.* FROM PART_DETAIL;"

'delete xml files from folder
    Kill strPath & "*.XML"

'advise job complete
    MsgBox "Load & Transform complete", vbInformation, "XML data upload"

End Sub
```

Edit Post:
I have tried adding the update string suggested by @June7 without success

```
' APPEND TO TABLES
    Application.ImportXML strPath & "temp.xml", acAppendData

    Debug.Print strPath & strFile
    rst.Edit
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE ES_Materials SET FilePath='" & strPath & strFile & "' WHERE FilePath Is Null"
    rst.MoveNext
    rst.Update
```

Comment: It's not available in XSLT 1.0 but you could send it as parameter when initiating the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you give me too much credit :). I am brand new to xml and xmlt so have no idea how to pass a parameter. I have vba code that I copied and maintained from another site to append the data to tables. How would I pass the parameter?

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with XML/XSLT. If you're calling the XSL transformation from VBA, you need to find out how to pass a parameter using VBA. Only then it will become a question of how to process the parameter in your XSLT stylesheet (which is fairly trivial). I know a little about XSLT, but nothing about VBA.

Comment: Exactly how are you accomplishing the transformation? Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694517/xml-xslt-access-vba-how-can-i-merge-all-child-elements-even-unknown-elements ? Perhaps would be simpler to update Access records after import.

Comment: You should post the vba code used

Comment: @KevinBrown  I have updated the post with the VBA code used to upload and transform the XML data

Comment: @June7 I have updated the post with the VBA code used to upload and transform the XML data

Comment: Well, I don't see any way to pass value to the transformation. So what about my suggestion to update records with filename after import?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431009/excel-vba-coding-for-xls-transformation-along-with-paramters

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k but that is way over my head :(

Comment: If you can't send it as a parameter, then the only other way for the XSLT stylesheet to read it is from another XML file (with a hard-coded name and path). If that's not feasible, then look for a solution outside of XSLT.

Comment: @June7 Before I raised this question, I tried to use  rst.edit; rst!FilePath = strPath & strFile followed by rst.Update in the same transform procedure. The path & filename are not updated

Comment: I do wonder why this is of value if the files are deleted afterwards.

Comment: @June7 the path is not really relevant but the file name is... it is so that I can track what file contained what material information should users query it... I tried the code suggested, but the record was still not updated with the filename (see the updated / edited post)...

Comment: There is no need for `rst` object code. The `Execute` command running UPDATE action should directly edit all records in table that meet the criteria. If the records truly get created in ES_Materials and that table has text field called FilePath, the UPDATE should work. The UPDATE does assume FilePath field is null when records are created. See revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest running an UPDATE action on the newly imported records. I prefer CurrentDb.Execute instead of DoCmd.RunSQL. For one reason, don't need to use DoCmd.SetWarnings.

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE ES_Materials SET FilePath='" & strPath & strFile & "' WHERE FilePath Is Null"`

The UPDATE assumes FilePath field is null when records are created. If there is possibility field has empty string, then try different criteria:
`"' WHERE FilePath & '' = ''"`

Comment: You are a SUPERSTAR :). I was being a complete idiot the XML files update a set of tables which I then use in an append query to update the file ES_Materials. The currentdb.execute should have been on the original table because the append query is only run later. BUT thanks to your patience and advice I finally managed to get it right

Comment: And I should have noticed in your edit that you had the UPDATE action in wrong location in the procedure. Could place it after the OpenQuery command, which I assume is where ES_Materials. Also consider if the append query is constructed and run in VBA, the filepath could be incorporated there. Glad you got something working.

Comment: Or query EngineeringSpares could have parameter referencing unbound textbox set to the filepath/filename.